# Skype chat window is not opening by using Skype Id of user after login in android

Tags: android

I am implementing Skype Integration in my android application. I have a requirement to open chat window of Skype using Skype Id of user.
I have done this successfully, but the problem is that when I logged out from Skype and then open the the Skype from android application using the user Id
then it redirecting to login screen and after login with the same user Id, then the Skype application is goes in background and redirect to my android application.
So I want to open the chat window of Skype when I logged In with the id for which I am opening chat window. Please suggest me, How I can implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the code that you are using to show the Skype intent?

It should look similar to this :

```
Intent skypeIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
skypeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + user_name));
startActivity(skypeIntent);
```

In your manifest you need the following intent filter :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="skype" />
</intent-filter>
```